# Package for multivariate Garch Vech model for R?

Tags: r, garch, estimation, multivariate

I`m new to programming and searching a package for R which inherents the estimation for a Vech Garch(1,1). This is a multivariate Garch model which forms the residuals and the covariance matrix from a NxN matrix to a N(N+1)/2 vector. I can only find DCC and BEKK estimation.

Does somebody know a package or source of code for this estimation?

Comment: I have some experience with both GARCH models and R, but so far have not seen VECH-GARCH implemented in R.

Comment: Try with this:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmgarch/rmgarch.pdf
but I'm not sure there is what you want.

Comment: I already tried the rmgarch package, but no vech sadly. @Richard Hardy, do you know the BEKK code from Github https://github.com/vst/mgarch/blob/master/R/mvBEKK.est.R ? And are you experienced enough to give me an advice to rewrite it? I tried but I lag experience in programming.

Comment: No, sorry, I do not have enough experience with BEKK.

Comment: Ok, but have you ever performed an estimation for 210 parameters? If yes, how long did take the code to complete. And did you maybe used constrOptim() in it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the mgarch package, it's available at CRAN. In [this link](http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/book/Ch13.mgarch2ndEdition.ssc) you will find an example from Prof. Zivot.